# why do we use RAM model of computation for algorithmic analysis when it corresponds to harvard architecture?

Tags: algorithm, cpu-architecture, von-neumann, harvard-architecture

As per Wikipedia , RASP model of computation corresponds to von Neumann Architecture while RAM model of computation corresponds to Harvard Architecture and von Neumann architecture is closest to computers since we have ram memory in our computers which stores data as well as instructions in it , while RAM model has different program memory and different data memory , so why do we use RAM model for algorithmic analysis ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine

Comment: When analysing an algorithm we count the number of *steps* it takes, not how long it takes to run. If a step takes a cycle longer because the memory access must be delayed until a load/store port is available in the CPU, it doesn't change the total number of steps. Also we focus on asymptotic behaviour so we can ignore trivial differences like these ones. Simply put: in big scheme of things it doesn't matter!

Comment: So then why do we say that RASP model corresponds to Von Neumann architecture and RAM model corresponds to Harvard architecture when we have to do only asymptotic analysis , then why are there different models of computation defined ?

Comment: Models of computation arise from practical use (one purpose of the computational complexity theory is finding which ones are equivalent). From a complexity pov a model is implicitly defined and fixed. Some model is easier to use when analysing specific kinds of problems so having different models is good.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I got the basic insight of your explanation .

Answer (score 1):

Unless your algorithm uses self-modifying code, the distinction doesn't matter, for the reasons Margaret points out.

Also, as far as real hardware is concerned, (almost?) all modern CPUs that have a cache have split instruction/data L1 caches, so the actual CPU core is more Harvard-like than von Neumann.  Instruction-fetch rarely competes with data access.

Wikipedia's [Modified Harvard Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture#Modified_Harvard_architecture) article goes into more detail, and mentions other ways that mostly-Harvard architectures that can still be programmed by programs.